# Excel Macro how to disable rows?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Excel Worksheet with a macro. If you click on the sheet than a UserForm gets called where a User can save an appointment.

I tried to lock the first 3 rows in the Macro before where the Macro gets called.

```
    Sub Call_Userform()

If (Worksheets(ActiveSheet).Cells(3, 52)) Then

UserForm1.Show

Else: MsgBox "Please enter a valid..!"

End Sub
```

However this does not work. Is it possible to block the first 3 rows so the user cant click on them or change the name or whatever.

[image: picture]

The yellow rows have to be blocked so the user for example can not click on them to for example change the name from "Regeltermin" to "Test".

Is it possible to disable clicking on the first 3 rows?

Comment: Locking the cells has no effect without protecting the worksheet.

Comment: Yeah I need to lock them completly - the worksheet cant be locked because ppl need to use the functions and macro in it.

Comment: What does 'disable rows` should mean? To make them not editable? If yes, you must lock them and protect the sheet. Then, what do you expect from the code line `If (Worksheets(ActiveSheet).Cells(3, 52)) Then`? Besides, `Worksheets(ActiveSheet)` no make sense and can use instead `ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 52)`, what do you want checking? Should there be a Boolean variable in `Cells(3, 52)`?

Comment: It is usually done by unprotecting the worksheet before using a procedure on it, and then protecting it again.

Comment: What does "If you click on the sheet than a UserForm gets called" mean? Do you want using an event? What did you try, from this point of view?

Comment: Basically if u look at the screenshot - this is monday and the excel worksheet has every day of the week in it. If a User double clicks in the "allow" fields the a UserForm gets opened. If a User clicks on a Block field it should not open up. Wich it alreardy does but if I click on Regeltermin and then on an Allow field than it would still open up the Userform and change the name from Regeltermin to whatever...

Comment: @FaneDuru A UserForm opens up which already works. You can set appointments in that Form. The only thing I want is that it is not able to open up on the first 3 rows. AT BEST you cant even click these rows

Comment: If you would post the event code, we would be able to show you how to adapt it in a way to exclude the first three rows, without needing to 'disable' them... I also asked about your expectations from a specific code line you posted. Can you answer it?

Comment: @FaneDuru I could post the UserForm Code but isnt the Call_Userform() Sub and UserForm1.Show the part where the modal opens up? I thought that I can set the behavior on that part..

Comment: Who said to post the UserForm code? **You** said that your form is shown "If you click on the sheet". This cannot be done from the UserForm code! Only a sheet event can do it.

Comment: I cannot get you... I am asking again: What does "If you click on the sheet than a UserForm gets called" mean? You said that already works.

Comment: @FaneDuru Okay I found some more code in that whole vba thing.. I also got that sheet event which calls UserFrom1.Show - I will look into that and edit my question with the code if I need help - ty

Comment: So, this is not your code, you only try understanding it. Is this a correct understanding of the situation?

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes it is not my code and I am not a Excel/VBA specialist. I made some minor changes on the macro and in excel. I have now found more code in that makro that I am analysing, thanks again

Comment: Then, try firstly understanding it and only after that asking for help **on a specific problem**. Otherwise, when you prove that you do not know what are you talking about, our enthusiasm for helping you is diminishing... :)

Comment: @FaneDuru I thought I had the whole code analyzed already but I found new parts of it that I didnt know about^^

Comment: I would suggest you to look into worksheet events. `SelectionChange` if is just a matter of a click, as you say, or `Change` event, if it is triggered after something on the sheet is changed. **It the event only shows the form**, in both cases you can use/insert a simple code line (first line): `If Target.Row <=3 then Exit Sub`. This will make the event exiting when click on a cell in the first three rows...

Comment: @FaneDuru I have managed to yield a MsgBox that tells the user what to do after he clicks the first 3 rows. The only thing I need is to show the messagebox and also maybe just disable editing of that field or exit sub if it works for me, I will try - Thanks Fane

Comment: So, this is the way. You must prove that you know what is it about...

Comment: Maybe this will help https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4350-excel-prevent-data-entry-into-cell.html